# How do I create a GET request with parameters?

Tags: python, http, get, urllib2

By default, it seems (for me) that every `urlopen()` with parameters seems to send a POST request. How can I set the call to send a GET instead?

```
import urllib
import urllib2

params = urllib.urlencode(dict({'hello': 'there'}))
urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/get', params)
```

> urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: METHOD NOT ALLOWED

Comment: The code `dict({...})` is redundant, the `{...}` syntax already creates a dictionary, so you can just `urlencode({'hello': 'there'})`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could use, much the same way that post request:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

params = urllib.urlencode({'hello':'there', 'foo': 'bar'})
urllib2.urlopen('http://somesite.com/get?' + params)
```

The second argument should only be supplied when making POST requests, such as when sending a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, for example.

Comment: So close... `urlencode` doesn't add `?`.  Also, `dict({...})` is redundant, the `{...}` syntax already creates a `dict`.

Comment: Had to add `?` at the end of the URL, but works okay now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're right, @ Dietrich Epp. I copied the same code snippet of the questioner.

Comment: I edited the code snippet of my post to avoid doubts when someone reads.

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided.
Try `urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/get?hello=there')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a GET request then you want to pass query string.
You do that by placing a question-mark '?' at the end of your url before the params.

```
import urllib
import urllib2

params = urllib.urlencode(dict({'hello': 'there'}))
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/get/?' + params)
req.read()
```